# Python 3 tic tac toe using lists

Tags: python

My code wont work, I'm trying to get my input on line 5 to replace whatever number i inputted, to correspond with the board list.

```
board = ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|']
print (board[0:3])
print (board[4:7])
print (board[7:10])
player1 = int(input("type a number 0 - 9"))
player1 = int(board(int[input] == 'X'))
print (board[0:3])
print (board[4:7])
print (board[7:10])
```

Answer (score 1):

`board(int[input] == 'X')` isn't actually changing anything since `==` is for comparing two things, not assigning. What you probably want is `board[player1] = 'X'`. You don't need to convert anything to an `int` or assign anything to `player1` on line 6 since the `player1` variable will already be an `int` corresponding to where the user wants to place their "X"

Comment: ['|', '|', '|']
['|', '|', '|']
['|', '|', '|']
type a number 0 - 9 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/f27befa827fb67e8/main.py", line 6, in 
    player1 = board[player1] = 'X'
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: That line should just be `board[player1] = 'X'` not `player1 = board[player1] = 'X'`. You don't need to assign any new value to `player` after using it in the `input()` line